# BufferReader doesnt go through whole text

Tags: java, android, string, char, bufferedreader

I have a function that bolds certain characters. Everything works fine except that the string that I have at the beggining of the method is cut somewhere and returned in half,not as the whole string that is got in the beggining. Here is the code,I dont know where is my mistake.

```
public String boldovanjeAkorada(String text)
{
    String konacan = "<pre>";
    int i = 0;
    try {
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text));
        for (String line = buff.readLine(); line != null; line = buff.readLine()) {

            for(i=0;i<line.length();i++)
            {
                char slovo = line.charAt(i);
                if(slovo == ' ' )
                {
                   if(line.charAt(i-1)!=' ' && line.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
                   {
                       konacan = konacan + slovo;
                   }
                    else{
                       konacan = konacan + "&nbsp";
                   }
                }
                else if(slovo == '(') {
                    konacan = konacan + "<b>"+slovo;
                }
                else if(slovo == ')') {

                konacan = konacan + slovo + "</b>";
                }
                else {
                        konacan = konacan + slovo;
                    }
                }

            konacan = konacan + "<br />";

            }
            buff.close();

        }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    return konacan;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i<line.length();i++){...if(line.charAt(i-1)!=' ' && line.charAt(i+1)!=' ')...}` -- it may be out of bounds (`line.charAt(0)` and `line.chrAt(line.length())`)

Comment: Out of bounds would be a problem, but yield an exception. You *should* use a StringBuilder, but that wouldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
if(line.charAt(i-1)!=' ' && line.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
```

into

```
if( i>0 && line.charAt(i-1)!=' ' &&
    (i+1)<line.length() && line.charAt(i+1)!=' ')
```

Also add

```
return koncan + "</pre>"
```

Also you speed it up by using StringBuilder like this:

```
StringBuilder konacan = new StringBuilder("<pre>");
konacan.append("<b>"+slovo);
return konacan.append("</pre>").toString();
```

Comment: ... and there was no Exception printed out earlier?